# Do probability relations use the same rules as formal logic?

Tags: probability, logic, notation

I tried to show the probability of event $E$: Either $A$ is true, or $B$ is true, but $A$ and $B$ can't be true at the same time, given that all we know are quantities $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(A \cup B)$:

$$\Pr(E) = \Pr((A \cup B) \cap \lnot(A \cap B))$$

$$\Pr(E) = \Pr((A \cup B) \cap (1 - (A \cap B)))$$

$$\Pr(E) = \Pr((A \cup B) - (A \cup B)\cap(A \cap B))$$

$$\Pr(E) = \Pr((A \cup B) - (A \cap B))$$

Is this a correct proof? Does it make sense to use this notation or to treat it like a logic equation with $\lor, \land$, De Morgan's laws, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the probability of $P(A \cup B)$ is really the equivalent of asking about $P(x \in A \vee x \in B)$. Probabilities are nothing more than just operations on sets. Therefore, anything you're doing would just be a logical operator on sets. Therefore, you can apply the rules of mathematical logic on it.

Comment: The second expression for $\text{Pr}(E)$ does in fact follow from the first. Also in the first sentence, you write $P(x \in A \land x \in B)$ but it should be $\lor$.

Comment: Good catch. I hastily through that together to just point out the use of logical operators in probability. Thanks.

Comment: @6005 Why not? What's the correct way instead?

Comment: @ArukaJ Did you mean to notify me in that message?

Comment: Yes, did it not notify?

Answer (score 1):

Close.   Your proof is more correctly written using *set operators* rather than *logical connectives*:

Events are considered sets of outcomes.   Probability is a measure of these sets with certain properties; and *one* of these is that probability measure is: *additive for unions of disjoint sets*.

$$\begin{align}\Pr(E) ~=~& \Pr\big((A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B)^\complement\big) &~=~& \Pr(X\cap Y^\complement)
\\[1ex] ~=~& \Pr\big((A \cup B)  \setminus((A\cup B)\cap  (A \cap B))\big) &~=~& \Pr(X\setminus (X\cap Y))\\[1ex] ~=~& \Pr(A \cup B) - \Pr\big((A \cup B)\cap(A \cap B)) &~=~& \Pr(X)-\Pr(X\cap Y)\\[1ex] ~=~& \Pr(A \cup B) - \Pr(A \cap B) &~=~& \Pr(X)-\Pr(Y)
 \end{align}$$

---

Or perhaps more clearly:

When you have some events (sets) $X,Y$, where $Y\subseteq X$, then $Y$ and $X\setminus Y$ are disjoint; and also their union is $X$.    Hence by the afore mentioned rule that the measure is *additive for disjoint sets* we have:

$$\begin{align}\Pr(X) ~=~ &\Pr(Y\cup (X\setminus Y))\\[1ex] ~=~& \Pr(Y)+\Pr(X\setminus Y)\\[2ex]\therefore ~\Pr(X\cap Y^\complement)~=~& \Pr(X)-\Pr(Y) 
\end{align}$$

Now when $X=A\cup B, Y=A\cap B$, then $Y\subseteq X$, so we have established that:

$$\begin{align}\Pr\big((A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B)^\complement\big)~=~&\Pr(A\cup B)-\Pr(A\cap B)
\\[2ex]\therefore ~ \Pr(E)~=~&\Pr(A\cup B)-\Pr(A\cap B)
\end{align}$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Up at the top, how are you getting from one step to the next?

Comment: @ArukaJ As I said, down the bottom is more clear. But basically up top: (1) express the symmetric difference as the set difference of a set and a subset, (2) use the additivity of disjoint sets (3) simplify the set expressions.

Comment: Are you using identities at all? How do you go from the complement of A and B to the union of A and B and the intersection of the intersection of A and B, and suddenly the other intersection symbol is gone and replaced with a difference operator?

Comment: @ArukaJ Because $X\cap Y^\complement = X\setminus Y $ and $Y=X\cap Y$ (since $Y\subseteq X$, Therefore $X\cap Y^\complement = X\setminus (X\cap Y)$ .  Substitute with the given $X=A\cup B, Y=A\cap B$.

Comment: I am unclear now, I am unable to translate between what I did and what you did. Is there any difference between the difference operator and the minus sign?